# URL Rewrites linking to main URL

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

ALL our URL rewrites are now linking to the base URL. I only noticed this morning our biggest changes were updating to the latest patches. I looked at the backend and they are all correct 100%, but when clicking on one they only redirect to the main base URL.

As seen at [here](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/221532627098) the links on the left hand side MS OFFICE and below.

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 0):

I just uploaded my old .htaccess file which fixed it.

Specifically looks like;

> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.(.*)$ [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.(.*)$ [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

AND

> `#RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`

Are the only differences.

Hope this helps someone.